# C: "undefined reference to" and collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Tags: c, data-structures, makefile

I have trouble trying to compile a double linked list project from a certain programming book. The project is accompanied by some libraries that help with testing.

Here are the tests

```
#include "minunit.h"
#include <lcthw/list.h>
#include <assert.h>

static List *list = NULL;
char *test1 = "test1 data";
char *test2 = "test2 data";
char *test3 = "test3 data";

char *test_create()
{
    list = List_create();
    mu_assert(list != NULL, "Failed to create list.");

    return NULL;
}

char *test_destroy()
{
    List_clear_destroy(list);

    return NULL;
}

char *test_push_pop()
{
    List_push(list, test1);
    mu_assert(List_last(list) == test1, "Wrong last value.");

    List_push(list, test2);
    mu_assert(list_last(list) == test2, "Wrong last value");

    List_push(list, test3);
    mu_assert(List_last(list) == test3, "Wrong last value.");
    mu_assert(List_count(list) == 3, "Wrong count on push.");

    char *val = List_pop(list);
    mu_assert(val == test3, "Wrong value on pop.");

    val = List_pop(list);
    mu_assert(val == test2, "Wrong value on pop.");

    val = List_pop(list);
    mu_assert(val == test1, "Wrong value on pop.");
    mu_assert(List_count(list) == 0, "Wrong count after pop.");

    return NULL;
}

char *test_unshift()
{
    List_unshift(list, test1);
    mu_assert(List_first(list) == test1, "Wrong first value.");

    List_unshift(list, test2);
    mu_assert(List_first(list) == test2, "Wrong first value.");

    List_unshift(list, test3);
    mu_assert(List_first(list) == test3, "Wrong last value.");
    mu_assert(List_count(list) == 3, "Wrong count on unshift.");

    return NULL;
}

char *test_remove()
{
    // we only need to test the middle remove case since push/shift
    // already tests the other cases

    char *val = List_remove(list, list->first->next);
    mu_assert(val == test2, "Wrong removed element.");
    mu_assert(List_count(list) == 2, "Wrong count after remove.");
    mu_assert(List_first(list) == test3, "Wrong first after remove");
    mu_assert(List_last(list) == test1, "Wrong last after remove.");

    return NULL;
}

char *test_shift()
{
    mu_assert(List_count(list) != 0, "Wrong count before shift.");

    char *val = List_shift(list);
    mu_assert(val == test3, "Wrong value on shift.");

    val = List_shift(list);
    mu_assert(val == test1, "Wrong value on shift.");
    mu_assert(List_count(list) == 0, "Wrong count after shift.");

    return NULL;
}

char *all_tests()
{
    mu_suite_start();

    mu_run_test(test_create);
    mu_run_test(test_push_pop);
    mu_run_test(test_unshift);
    mu_run_test(test_remove);
    mu_run_test(test_shift);
    mu_run_test(test_destroy);

    return NULL;
}

RUN_TESTS(all_tests);
```

Also this is the Makefile I used for compiling the whole project:

```
CFLAGS=-g -O2 -Wall -Wextra -Isrc -rdynamic -DNDEBUG $(OPTFLAGS)
#LDLIBS=-ldl $(OPTLIBS)
PREFIX?=/usr/local

SOURCES=$(wildcard src/**/*.c src/*.c)
OBJECTS=$(patsubst %.c,%.o,$(SOURCES))

TEST_SRC=$(wildcard tests/*_tests.c)
TESTS=$(patsubst %.c,%,$(TEST_SRC))

TARGET=build/liblcthw.a
SO_TARGET=$(patsubst %.a,%.so,$(TARGET))

# The Target Build
all: $(TARGET) $(SO_TARGET) tests

dev: CFLAGS=-g -Wall -Isrc -Wall -Wextra $(OPTFLAGS)
dev: all

$(TARGET): CFLAGS += -fPIC
$(TARGET): build $(OBJECTS)
    ar rcs $@ $(OBJECTS)
    ranlib $@
$(SO_TARGET): $(TARGET) $(OBJECTS)
    $(CC) -shared -o $@ $(OBJECTS)

build:
    @mkdir -p build
    @mkdir -p bin

# The Unit Tests
.PHONY: tests
tests: CFLAGS += $(TARGET)
tests: $(TESTS)
    sh ./tests/runtests.sh

# The Cleaner
clean:
    rm -rf build $(OBJECTS) $(TESTS)
    rm -f tests/tests.log
    find . -name ".gc*" -exec rm {} \;
    rm -rf `find . -name ".dSYM" -print`

#The Install
install: all
    install -d $(DESTDIR)/$(PREFIX)/lib/
    install $(TARGET) $(DESTDIR)/$(PREFIX)/lib/

#The Checker
check:
    @echo Files with potentially dangerous function.
    @egrep '[^_.>a-zA-Z0-9](str(n?cpy|n?cat|xfrm|n?dup|str|pbrk|tok|_)\
                |stpn?cpy|a?sn?printf|byte_)' $(SOURCES) || true
```

When I run make I get this:

```
cc -g -O2 -Wall -Wextra -Isrc -rdynamic -DNDEBUG  -fPIC   -c -o src/lcthw/list.o src/lcthw/list.c
ar rcs build/liblcthw.a src/lcthw/list.o
ranlib build/liblcthw.a
cc -shared -o build/liblcthw.so src/lcthw/list.o
cc -g -O2 -Wall -Wextra -Isrc -rdynamic -DNDEBUG  build/liblcthw.a    tests/list_tests.c   -o tests/list_tests
In file included from tests/list_tests.c:1:0:
tests/list_tests.c: In function ‘main’:
tests/minunit.h:16:38: warning: parameter ‘argc’ set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-parameter]
 #define RUN_TESTS(name) int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {\
                                      ^
tests/list_tests.c:107:1: note: in expansion of macro ‘RUN_TESTS’
 RUN_TESTS(all_tests);
 ^
/tmp/ccFfwxRB.o: In function `test_create':
/home/pxcel/liblcthw/tests/list_tests.c:12: undefined reference to `List_create'
/tmp/ccFfwxRB.o: In function `test_destroy':
/home/pxcel/liblcthw/tests/list_tests.c:20: undefined reference to `List_clear_destroy'
/tmp/ccFfwxRB.o: In function `test_push_pop':
/home/pxcel/liblcthw/tests/list_tests.c:27: undefined reference to `List_push'
/home/pxcel/liblcthw/tests/list_tests.c:30: undefined reference to `List_push'
/home/pxcel/liblcthw/tests/list_tests.c:33: undefined reference to `List_push'
/home/pxcel/liblcthw/tests/list_tests.c:37: undefined reference to `List_pop'
/home/pxcel/liblcthw/tests/list_tests.c:40: undefined reference to `List_pop'
/home/pxcel/liblcthw/tests/list_tests.c:43: undefined reference to `List_pop'
/tmp/ccFfwxRB.o: In function `test_unshift':
/home/pxcel/liblcthw/tests/list_tests.c:52: undefined reference to `List_unshift'
/home/pxcel/liblcthw/tests/list_tests.c:55: undefined reference to `List_unshift'
/home/pxcel/liblcthw/tests/list_tests.c:58: undefined reference to `List_unshift'
/tmp/ccFfwxRB.o: In function `test_remove':
/home/pxcel/liblcthw/tests/list_tests.c:70: undefined reference to `List_remove'
/tmp/ccFfwxRB.o: In function `test_shift':
/home/pxcel/liblcthw/tests/list_tests.c:83: undefined reference to `List_shift'
/home/pxcel/liblcthw/tests/list_tests.c:86: undefined reference to `List_shift'
/tmp/ccFfwxRB.o: In function `test_destroy':
/home/pxcel/liblcthw/tests/list_tests.c:20: undefined reference to `List_clear_destroy'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
<builtin>: recipe for target 'tests/list_tests' failed
make: *** [tests/list_tests] Error 1
```

I have googled the errors that I get and the answers I got thus far are suggesting to check if I have typos or if I haven't linked the files correctly. Could the latter be the case?

Comment: `undefined reference` is a linker error, so there's nothing syntactically wrong with the code

Comment: Most won't parse through all the unrelated clutter to find the issue. Have you tried reducing this as much as possible (to a minimal example)?

Comment: @Treeston That is good advice, try adding a useful reference e.g. by adding `[mcve]` to your comment, which gives you [mcve].

Comment: looks like `list.o` is not making it to the object list. Put `$(info OBJECTS = $(OBJECTS))` below the object assignment in the makefile and see what prints out

Comment: Trace the makefile and observe how linking is made, looks like your are not linking with the library.

Comment: @Treeston you are right, I edited out the code that is not needed.

Comment: Also @yano I tried what you suggested and seems that list.o is in the object list.

Comment: hmmm. The order of linked objects matters too. All the link errors are referencing functions in `link.c` from what I could tell, so one way or another that object code isn't making it to the appropriate place in the linker invocation. I'm no makefile expert... listing the linker commands being run rather than just the errors might be helpful.

Comment: Show the linking command line, for pity's sake.  That's what's causing the trouble — we need to see it to be able to help you.  But it looks like you aren't linking the library code.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I am using the --trace command but I am not making any sense of what I am seeing. Sorry, I am fairly new to this.

Comment: I'm not sure what `--trace` has to do with anything (I've never needed to use it).  There should be a line (or possibly a few lines) just before the 'undefined reference' messages spew forth that contain(s) the command that is executed.  If there is no such line, stop using `make -s` (silent mode) or `.SILENT:` directives (always-silent mode), or using `@` markers before your commands, or …  There are lots of ways to stop `make` telling you what its doing.  However, you need to know what it is doing.

Comment: @yano I added whatever there was before the errors, is this what you meant?

Comment: yes. My guess is that if you move `build/liblcthw.a` to the end of the `cc -g -O2 -Wall -Wextra -Isrc -rdynamic -DNDEBUG  build/liblcthw.a    tests/list_tests.c   -o tests/list_tests` these linker errors will go away, the reason being that `list_tests` calls functions in that library. Linker order matters. In terms of fixing it in your makefile... I'd need a longer look. I'm certainly no expert in these things

Comment: Thank you for including the command line.  That makes it easy.  You have: `cc …  build/liblcthw.a  tests/list_tests.c -o tests/list_tests`.  You must list the libraries — especially static libraries with `.a` suffixes — after the (source or) object files: `cc … tests/list_tests.c  build/liblcthw.a  -o tests/list_tests`.  Yes, the order of the options really matters!  (On some systems, you sometimes get away with listing shared libraries before object files.  On *all* systems, listing libraries *after* object files always works.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have:

```
cc … build/liblcthw.a tests/list_tests.c -o tests/list_tests
```

You must list the libraries — especially static libraries with `.a` suffixes — after the (source or) object files:

```
cc … tests/list_tests.c build/liblcthw.a -o tests/list_tests
```

Yes, the order of the library and file options really matters!  (On some systems, you sometimes get away with listing shared libraries before object files.  On *all* systems, listing libraries *after* object files *always* works.  Do what works!)  Some options are more mobile; for example, the `-o tests/list_tests` option could appear earlier in the command line without problem.  But libraries (`-l…` options, and also simple references to the library, as in this example) should appear on the command line after object files (or the source file if you don't compile the source to an object file before you link).

Comment: You are right, this solved my problem. The fix in the `makefile` was just to change the `CFLAGS` in the `tests: CFLAGS += $(TARGET)` with`LDLIBS`